# How to return strings based on difference, whether + or - with Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, difference

If I want the IDE (i.e Pydroid) to return different strings based on the difference between a Variable's stored value and the other values of a given range, how would I do that? I know I can do it with Set operations, but are there any methods otherwise?

For example: Let's say the game "hot or cold". If you are asked to guess a number between 0 and 10 (so, `range(1,10)`), and the Winning number is 4 'W=4', I want the string "Almost" to print out for input 3 or 5, the string "hot" for 2 or 6, "warm" for 1 or 7, 8 should return "cold", and
"couldn't be further" for 9.

I tried:

```
print("Can you guess the winning number between 0 and 10?")
A=int(input('Pleasant picks: '))
if A not in range(1,10):
        print("That is not an option...")
elif A == 4:
print("You win!")
else:
    if A is int(3) or int(5):
         print("Almost...")
    elif A is int(2) or int(6):
         print("You're hot")
    elif A is int(1) or int(7):
         print("Warm, but not as hot as your mom")
    elif A is int(8):
         print("cold...")
    elif A is int(9):
        print("Couldn't be further")
    else:
        print(i)
```

It only returns "Almost" for all choices but 4 and out of range which work right...

And how do I loop this while also returning the count of attempts?

Comment: `or int(5)` is always true

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
def case(c):
    options = {
        4: "you win",
        3: "Almost",
        5: "Almost",
        2: "You're hot",
        6: "You're hot",
        1: "Warm, but not as hot as your mom",
        7: "Warm, but not as hot as your mom",
        8: "cold...",
        9: "Couldnt be further"
    }
    
    return options.get(c,"That is not an option")

print("Can you guess the winning number between 0 and 10?")
count = 0
while True:
    A=int(input('Pleasant picks: '))
    count+=1
    print(case(A))
```

Comment: then u can add logic for the attempts using count variable